# I add the uiview constraints on swift playgrounds , but the constraints doesn't work , why?

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout

Why the uiview constraints doesn't  work ?  I add the constraints of uiview height and width and the position relation , but the they doesn't work, why ?

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class myview : UIView{
    override init(frame:CGRect)
    {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}
required init(coder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: coder)!
}
func setcolor(color : UIColor){
    self.backgroundColor=UIColor.green
}

}
let my1:myview = myview(frame: CGRect(x: 99 , y: 99, width: 99,   height: 99))
let my2:myview = myview(frame:CGRect(x:50,y:50,width:50,height:50))
my2.setcolor(color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.952941179275513, green: 0.686274528503418, blue: 0.133333340287209, alpha: 1.0))
my1.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
my1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
my2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
let leadingheight=NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: my2, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 120)
let leadingwidth=NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: my2, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 60)
my1
my2.addConstraints([leadingheight,leadingwidth])

my1.addSubview(my2)

let cons2:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: my2, attribute: .left , relatedBy: .equal, toItem: my1, attribute: .left , multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20)

my2.addConstraints([cons2])
my2.updateConstraints()
my1.updateConstraints()

my1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made your example work.  See the inline comments for explanations:

```
// Note: This frame will be ignored once translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraint is set to false
let my1 = myview(frame: CGRect(x: 99, y: 99, width: 99, height: 99))
let my2 = myview(frame:CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50))
my2.setcolor(color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.952941179275513, green: 0.686274528503418, blue: 0.133333340287209, alpha: 1.0))
my1.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

// Use constraints, not frame for size of my1 and my2
my1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
my2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// Frame not used, so set constraints for width and height of my1
let my1height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: my1, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 200)
let my1width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: my1, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 200)

// Frame not used, so set constraints for width and height of my2
let leadingheight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: my2, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 120)
let leadingwidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: my2, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 60)

// Activate the constraints instead of adding them to a view
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([my1width, my1height, leadingheight, leadingwidth])

my1.addSubview(my2)

let cons2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: my2, attribute: .left , relatedBy: .equal, toItem: my1, attribute: .left , multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20)

// This is how to activate a single constraint
cons2.isActive = true

my1
```

---

**Notes:**

1. Since iOS 8, the proper way of enabling constraints is to activate them instead of adding them to a view.  Activating them tells iOS to add them to the proper views; if you add them to the views yourself you have to be careful to add them to the *correct* views.  Your `cons2` should have been added to `my1` not `my2` because the constraint involves `my1` and it is the parent of `my2`.
2. Once you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`, the `frame` is ignored, so you need to make sure you have constraints to fully specify the size of your view.
3. Don't call `updateConstraints`.  If anything is needed to kick *Auto Layout* into action in the Playground, you can call `layoutIfNeeded()` on your view.
4. *Style note:* Let Swift interpret the types of variables when possible.
5. Don't use `.init`.  The Swift way is to just use the class/struct name.  (eg. `NSLayoutConstraint(item:...)` instead of `NSLayoutConstraint.init(item...)`)

Answer (score 0):

**Remove**

```
my1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
my2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
```

If you use CGRect , dont need to `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`. You can use this with AutoLayout constraints

Comment: no，I tried with what you said, but the result is the same . actually , the constraints doesn't effective from beginning .  you cann try with xcode just copy the code and display . is there any problem ?

Comment: actually i just  want to change the height and width of the my2 (UIview) and its position